# PowerBI: Aggregate Measure correctly by condition on DATEDIFF

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, dax, aggregation, datediff

I have the following Table:

[BaseTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84WOG.png)

It represents processes with a certain category.

And there is also a Date Table over column TIMESTAMP.

I would like to show a Measure based on another Measure that calculates the Date-Difference until the selected Date.

So first this is how I calculate the Date-Difference:

```
AGE = 
VAR SELECTED_DATE = CALCULATE(MAX(DATUM[Date]), ALLSELECTED(DATUM))
VAR STARTDATE_PROCESS = Calculate(MAX(Workflow[MIN_TIMESTAMP]),DATUM[Date]<=MAX(DATUM[Date]), ALL(DATUM[Date]))
RETURN
DATEDIFF(STARTDATE_PROCESS,SELECTED_DATE,DAY)
```

Now I want to use a Measure which depends on the result of AGE, like

```
NEW = IF([AGE]<=3,CALCULATE(COUNT(Workflow[PROCESS]),DATUM[Date]<=MAX(DATUM[Date]),ALL(DATUM)))
```

or

```
OLD = IF([AGE]>3,CALCULATE(COUNT(Workflow[PROCESS]),DATUM[Date]<=MAX(DATUM[Date]),ALL(DATUM)))
```

The Measures AGE, OLD and NEW look like that with the Base Table:

[Measures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MebSW.png)

As you can see the aggregation is not working correctly:

[Result_Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Daul.png)

But it should be like that

[Result_Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCcwq.png)

Any idea how to fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: what is your exact report requirement?

Comment: Want to show how many processes within a group are old or new depending on the date I select.

Comment: You already have those and I can see in "Result" Image, if your result image is wrong, please post how your final result should look like, Also in base table image there is not column with "Age", please update your basetable image aswell for  dataset, will try to give you solution tomorrow.

Comment: cool, thank you! I've updated the description. Good luck, looking foreward! :)

Comment: one more update - so this descripes my problem very detailed - hope it helps!

Comment: Working on the issue, will update once done... created dummy data for the solution.

Comment: Is the solution working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that the subtotal is calculated at a whole different context, and because your Age measure is based on the `MAX(Workflow[MIN_TIMESTAMP])` that won't take into account that there can be multiple processes.

To do what you want, you need to change the `New` and `Old` measures to perform an aggregation per process and then return the result of that. Something like this:

```
New_agg = 
VAR tbl = ADDCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Workflow[Process]), ALL('Date')), "age", [Age], "count_process", CALCULATE(COUNT(Workflow[Process]), ALL('Date')))
RETURN SUMX(tbl, IF([age]<=3, [count_process]))
```

[Demo File](http://www.filedropper.com/demo1_1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work unfortunatelly no result :(

Comment: Play with the formula, it will be some variation of this. I notice I don't have the `ALL(Datum)` cause in my file I didn't create a date table and used a fixed date instead.

Comment: Played but no success. Last thing I tried was 
`
New_agg = 
VAR tbl = SUMMARIZE(Workflow,Workflow[PROCESS], "age", [AGE], "count_process", CALCULATE(COUNT(Workflow[PROCESS]),ALL(DATUM)))
RETURN SUMX(tbl, IF([age]<3, [count_process]))
`
one more hint? :)

Comment: Hi, please try the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, as i disconnected the date table it worked with 
NEW2 = 
VAR tbl = ADDCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Workflow[Process]), ALL('DATUM')), "age", [Age], "count_process", CALCULATE(COUNT(Workflow[Process]),Workflow[TIMESTAMP]<=SELECTEDVALUE(DATUM[Date])))
RETURN SUMX(tbl, IF([age]<=3, [count_process]))

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if below solution is working

Unfortunately I am unable to generate the dummy data that you have been using, so Created my own data for developing the solution.

[image]

Now from this data I have calculated the difference of dates and put it as Age

[image]

Now to get the count of process for the condition like yours, I have created two formulas and the result is:

Logic I followed here is, instead of creating measure I have created columns and took the sum of those columns which will give the data you need as sum of those columns.

Column for New:

```
New = IF((Sheet1[Age]) > 20, 1,0)
```

Column for Old:

```
Old = IF((Sheet1[Age]) < 20, 1,0)
```

Now place both formulas in "**Values**" and take **sum** as the aggregation.

Final result is

[image]

Comment: Your Age formula doesn't do what is required in the question